# php dynamic page content based on url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, there are 3 urls:

```
example.com/first
example.com/middle
example.com/last
```

In my sql db, there is table with each terms that correspond to related posts:

```
ID    NAME    POSTS

1     first   12,3,343
2     middle  23,1,432
3     last    21,43,99
```

So if an user visits `example.com/first`, then I want to show posts of "12,3,343" and other posts based on what url they are visiting.

Now, this is the sequence how it would work in my head:

1. User types "example.com/first"
2. js (ajax) or something detects the url (in this case, detects `"first"`).
3. the term is sent to php query.
4. Gets appropriate info then sends it out (either by ajax or something else).

Am I approaching this right?
How does the server detects what url was requested? I supposed I can skip the first two steps if I know how the server detects the url and I can query the correct info directly instead of relying on js to detect it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mention ajax, I assume you are not navigating away from the page your are on. Am I correct?

If so, you have to create another php file to respond to the requests:

1. A request is sent to `file.php` with the url as a query string
2. In `file.php`, let it query the DB and `json_encode` the data.
3. Retrieve the data and update the fields without navigating away.

PHP is only executed once (Server-side). if you want to execute another query you have to either navigate to other URL or just send your request to a php file via ajax.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, send the last term of url as the request via ajax to the file php, then get the data, and send it back as json. Am I correct?

Comment: @RyanPicard Yes, as you dont have to repeat yourself with`www.example.com`. But If you want to send the whole url as a query string, you should use `"file.php?url="+encodeURI("example.com/first")`. Just to avoid the `/` in the url being executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the segments of a url request using below statements

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $url);
```

Now you have all the segments in an array ($segments)
`print_r($segments)` to get the index of the segment you require.

Now compare that segment with your value
For Eg :

```
if( $segments[2] == 'first')
{
//Your Piece of code
}
```